# Perl Remove Stop Words from multiple files

Tags: perl, file, stop-words

I have read so many forms on how to remove stop words from files, my code remove many other things but I want to include also stop words. This is how far I reached, but I don't know what I am missing. Please Advice

```
use Lingua::StopWords qw(getStopWords);
my $stopwords = getStopWords('en');

chdir("c:/perl/input");
@files = <*>;

foreach $file (@files) 
  {
    open (input, $file);

    while (<input>) 
      {
        open (output,">>c:/perl/normalized/".$file);
    chomp;
    #####What should I write here to remove the stop words#####
    $_ =~s/<[^>]*>//g;
    $_ =~ s/\s\.//g;
    $_ =~ s/[[:punct:]]\.//g;
    if($_ =~ m/(\w{4,})\./)
    {
    $_ =~ s/\.//g;
    }
    $_ =~ s/^\.//g;
    $_ =~ s/,/' '/g;
    $_ =~ s/\(||\)||\\||\/||-||\'//g;

    print output "$_\n";

      }
   }

close (input);
close (output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Always use these in your Perl programs.
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename qw(basename);
use Lingua::StopWords qw(getStopWords);

# It's often better to build scripts that take their input
# and output locations as command-line arguments rather than
# being hard-coded in the program.
my $input_dir   = shift @ARGV;
my $output_dir  = shift @ARGV;
my @input_files = glob "$input_dir/*";

# Convert the hash ref of stop words to a regular array.
# Also quote any regex characters in the stop words.
my @stop_words  = map quotemeta, keys %{getStopWords('en')};

for my $infile (@input_files){
    # Open both input and output files at the outset.
    # Your posted code reopened the output file for each line of input.
    my $fname   = basename $infile;
    my $outfile = "$output_dir/$fname";
    open(my $fh_in,  '<', $infile)  or die "$!: $infile";
    open(my $fh_out, '>', $outfile) or die "$!: $outfile";

    # Process the data: you need to iterate over all stop words
    # for each line of input.
    while (my $line = <$fh_in>){
        $line =~ s/\b$_\b//ig for @stop_words;
        print $fh_out $line;
    }

    # Close the files within the processing loop, not outside of it.
    close $fh_in;
    close $fh_out;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for these handful tips it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The stop words are the keys of `%$stopwords` which have the value 1, i.e.:

```
@stopwords = grep { $stopwords->{$_} } (keys %$stopwords);
```

It might happen be true that the stop words are just the keys of `%$stopwords`, but according the the `Lingua::StopWords` docs you also need to check the value associated with the key.

Once you have the stop words, you can remove them with code like this:

```
# remove all occurrences of @stopwords from $_

for my $w (@stopwords) {
  s/\b\Q$w\E\b//ig;
}
```

Note the use of `\Q...\E` to quote any regular expression meta-characters that might appear in the stop word. Even though it is very unlikely that stop words will contains meta-characters, this is a good practice to follow any time you want to represent a literal string in a regular expression.

We also use `\b` to match a word boundary. This helps ensure that we won't a stop word that occurs in the middle of another word. Hopefully this will work for you - it depends a lot on what your input text is like - i.e. do you have punctuation characters, etc.

Comment: Thank you so, it worked pretty fine, and thank you for your explanation.